# Find MAPI objects not released

Tags: release, mapi

If using MAPI, the final command that terminates the session hangs until all objects have been released.  My question is, when this never happens, how can I find which objects are being held?  I had sort of expected to find a 'list objects held' type function, and clearly there is one otherwise the termination function could not be waiting - but can I access it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such list, and it all depends on the particular store or address book provider.

Answer (score 0):

Extended MAPI doesn't provide such lists. The only possible way is to release COM objects in the code instantly. The [IUnknown::Release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317(v=vs.85).aspx) method returns the new reference count. Call this method when you no longer need to use an interface pointer. If you are writing a method that takes an in-out parameter, call Release on the pointer you are passing in before copying the out-value on top of it.

When the reference count on an object reaches zero, Release must cause the interface pointer to free itself. When the released pointer is the only existing reference to an object (whether the object supports single or multiple interfaces), the implementation must free the object.